# Google Earth API - Transforming ED50 / WGS84

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin, wgs84

I'm developing a web application, coding in JS, including Google Earth API. I'm looking for a way to **convert points from the used WGS84 to ED50 and vice versa**. 
If google itself doesn't give this option, there is another way to that in JS?
Unfortunately, proj4js cannot help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I guess there is no really simple way for that.

You need to convert from ED50 latitude, longitude and ellipsoidal height/altitude to Cartesian coordinates (X, Y, Z) in a corresponding earth-centered, earth-fixed geocentric system. Then, you can convert to from Cartesian coordinates to WGS84 latitude, longitude, and ellipsoidal height/altitude.

Reference:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de&fromgroups=#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/0Rt9A3qKsqo
- http://mind.cog.jhu.edu/courses/680/octave/Installers/Octave/Octave.OSX10.6/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/toolbox/shared/mapgeodesy/geodetic2ecef.m